# The output image is not a proper circular cropped image using Pillow in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

```py
layout = Image.open(r"./meme_templates/heaven.jpg")
asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=128)
data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
pfp = Image.open(data)
bigsize = (pfp.size[0] * 3, pfp.size[1] * 3)
mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
mask = mask.resize(pfp.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
mask = ImageChops.darker(mask, pfp.split()[-1])
pfp.putalpha(mask)
pfp = pfp.resize((93, 93))
layout.paste(pfp, (162, 92))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(layout)
font1 = ImageFont.truetype("./OpenSans-Bold.ttf", 32)
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("./BullettoKilla.ttf", 24)
font3 = ImageFont.truetype("./BullettoKilla.ttf", 46)
imgdesc = f"{member}"
w, h = draw.textsize(imgdesc)
imgmssg = f"Welcome to DIVINE! Hope you have a blessed stay!"
draw.text((275, 112), imgdesc, (0, 0, 0), font1)
draw.text((45, 217), imgmssg, (0, 0, 0), font2)
draw.text((194, 14), "WELCOME!", (0, 0, 0), font3)
layout.save(r"./meme_templates/heavenedit.jpg")
await channel.send(file=discord.File(r"./meme_templates/heavenedit.jpg"))
```

This is my code.
And my output is coming in the following way,

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzvdY.jpg): [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzvdY.jpg)https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8LzM.png

I want my output to be the profile picture to be a perfect circular cropped image.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used much PIL, but the issue might be when pasting the image, you haven't passed the alpha mask.

```py
layout.paste(pfp, (162, 92), pfp)
```